# eval() fails to evaluate innerHTML

Tags: html, eval, innerhtml

I have following code structure

```
<script>  
function load_script()
{
  eval( document.getElementById("mydiv").innerHTML );
}
</script>

<div id="mydiv">function sum(a,b){return a+b;}</div>

<input type="button" onclick="load_script()" value="Load Script">

<input type='button' value = 'Get Sum' onclick='sum(1,2)'>
```

When I click on 'Load Script' button to run `load_script()` function, the `innerHTML` is not parsed by `eval()` and as a result, the 'Get Sum' button always fails. Why is it like this?

Comment: What exactly are you expecting to happen here?? I think you need to start again from the beginning with writing Javascript

Comment: Blade0rz, Thanks for your beautiful answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

below code worked for me.

```
<script>  
function load_script()
{
  eval( document.getElementById("mydiv").innerHTML + "");
}
</script>

<div id="mydiv">sum = function (a,b){return a+b;}</div>

<input type="button" onclick="load_script()" value="Load Script">

<input type='button' value = 'Get Sum' onclick='alert(sum(1,2));'>
```

Comment: `<div id="mydiv">sum = function sum(a,b){return a+b;}</div>` this also will work.

Comment: This is really working on IE, Chrome and Firefox. DO you know such behaviour occurs? Thanks Ramesh.